# Why I get error when I try to declare local variable?

Tags: angular, typescript

I bew to the typescript.
In my function in the component I try to declare a local variable "contains":

```
  setUpgrade($event) {
    
     contains : Boolean = this.selectedUpgrades.includes($event);

    //some logic
    
    }
```

but on this row:

```
 contains : Boolean = this.selectedUpgrades.includes($event);
```

on the Boolean I get this error:

```
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'BooleanConstructor'.
```

Why I get an error on the variable declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Boolean` type is something that you'd get if you invoked the Boolean constructor:

```
const somethingWeird = new Boolean(Math.random() < 0.5);
```

This is almost never what you want - it can behave quite oddly. For example, a Boolean object containing `false` is truthy. Its `typeof` is also `object`, not `boolean`. Use the `boolean` type instead.

```
const contains : boolean = this.selectedUpgrades.includes($event);
```

Or, even better, leave out the type annotation entirely, and let TS infer it automatically:

```
const contains = this.selectedUpgrades.includes($event);
```

That's usually preferable, since it leads to less boilerplate and less code that needs to be read.